# uWSGI: how to serve static files from root and an app from a sub directory?

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, cloud9-ide

I am using Cloud 9 IDE to build a website.  My goal is to serve a static website from the site root '/index.html' and so on.  The content in this site will be regenerated on a schedule (daily in this example).  At the '/admin' and '/api' endpoints I want to serve a couple of flask apps.

Because this is being built on the Cloud 9 IDE, I do not have access to the proxy server configuration.  I have to serve everything to one port using the HTML protocol.  uWSGI is capable of doing exactly this.  I am struggling with my configuration file though:

```
#uwsgi.ini
[uwsgi]
static-index = index.html
static-map2 = /=/home/ubuntu/workspace/generated-site
static-map2 = /static=/home/ubuntu/workspace/static-assets

mount = /admin=admin.py
mount = /api=api.py
manage-script-name = true

master = true
processes = 5

socket=0.0.0.0:8080 
protocol=http
```

Requests to `/admin` and `/api` work as expected returning a result or 404 error.

Requests to `/` and `/index.html` both return `generated-site/index.html` as expected.
A request to `/no_exist.html` returns `404 Not Found` as expected.

My problem is with the second `static-map2`.  A request to `/static/test.html` came back `404 Not Found` (I put an html file there to test).

Comment: Anyone who is interested should be able to see a demo app @ https://ide.c9.io/cstrutton/test-uwsgi

Comment: For whoever might need this, I figured it out...  /static/test.html serves up static-assets/static/test.html

Answer (score 1):

`static-map2` keep the path portion of the URL for its search so the request `/static/test.html` will be mapped to the file

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/static-assets/static/test.html
```

---

You most probably want the simple `static-map` which strips the path from the URL before mapping to the file-system. So a request to `/static/test.html` will search for the file

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/static-assets/test.html
```